# Sending two element from the list in python to the unix shell command

Tags: python, unix

I have a file which contains the list of filesnames:

List:

```
Sample1_R1_L1.bam
Sample1_R2_L1.bam
Sample2_R1_L1.bam
Sample2_R2_L1.bam
```

.......

I want to run a unix command that merges each pair of files:

$ `samtools merge Sample1_merged_output.bam Sample1_R1_L1.bam Sample1_R2_L1.bam`

I was thinking I  can achieve this by using the for loop in python which takes two elements from the list of file names and runs the "subprocess" to call the unix command. I found a post which helped to access two elements at a time but I can not pass the names of the file to the unix shell:

```
for i,d in enumerate(list):
    if i < (len(list) - 1):
        print d + ' ' + list[i+1]
        # print d + ' ' + list[i+1]
```

any suggestions to achieve this are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `argv` to get arguments.

```
from sys import argv
print argv[1]
```

Result will be:

```
merge
```

Then your code would be something like:

```
list2merge = argv[2:]
for i,d in enumerate(list2merge):
    print str(i) + ' ' + str(d)
```

**UPDATE**

You should not use list as variable name, since it's reserved.